# Can I Create a Database and Tables in One SQL Command From PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Can I do something like this? I keep getting an error at the first 'CREATE TABLE point.

```
CREATE DATABASE T2T_$grouporg; 
            CREATE TABLE T2T_$grouporg.Members LIKE T2T_Main.Members; 
            CREATE TABLE T2T_$grouporg.Events LIKE T2T_Main.Events; 
            CREATE TABLE T2T_$grouporg.Taskers LIKE T2T_Main.Taskers
```

I tried separating out the CREATE DATABASE and CREATE TABLES into different mysqli_query statements.  The Database gets cretaed, but I get the same error with:

```
$create_tables = "CREATE TABLE T2T_$grouporg.Memebers LIKE T2T_Main.Members; 
                CREATE TABLE T2T_$grouporg.Events LIKE T2T_Main.Events; 
                CREATE TABLE T2T_$grouporg.Taskers LIKE T2T_Main.Taskers";
                $creat_tables = mysqli_query($dbconnect,$create_tables) or die("Create Table Error: " . mysqli_error($dbconnect) . "<BR><BR><BR>" . $create_tables);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: PHP has like 4 different builtin extensions that allow to run queries against a MySQL database. You should explain which one you are using, what code you've written and what error you're getting.

Comment: Have you already created database `T2T_Main`?

Comment: If you’re using [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query), it doesn’t support the execution of multiple statements at once by default.

Comment: This is the full error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE T2T_mark.Events LIKE T2T_Main.Events; CREATE TABLE T2T_mar' at line 2`

Comment: I tried separating out the CREATE DATABASE and CREATE TABLES into different

Comment: [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/mysqli_query) does also only allow the execution of one statement at once. If you want to execute multiple statements at once, use [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://php.net/mysqli_multi_query) instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. You cannot execute multiple statements with `mysqli_query`, but you can with `mysqli_multi_query`!